# Gitlab CI raising "unexpected end of file" error on nested multiline string

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `switch case` bash statement in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file where I use `cat <<EOF >> ... EOF` statement, but it doesn't like and keeps failing.

Here is the block raising error :

```
build-yaml-manifest:
........
........

  script:
     - |
        shopt -s nocasematch
        echo "Checking overlay"
        case $APP_NAME in
          projecthub)
            echo "We are building an instance of $APP_NAME"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            cp ../../base/overlays/projecthub/* ../../base/
            - |
            cat <<EOF >> ../../base/kustomization.yaml
              - service-backend.yaml
              - deployment-backend-talk2me.yaml
              - persistentvolumeclaim-backend.yaml
            EOF
            ;;
          *)
            echo "We are building a basic web application instance"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            ;;
        esac
........
```

The above code causes gitlab ci to fail with an "***unexpected end of file"*** error message, whether `$APP_NAME` value matches the cases or switch to default. The whole block make the pipeline fail.

I tried many syntaxes but it fails.

if I try this syntax :

```
build-yaml-manifest:
........
........

  script:
     - |
        shopt -s nocasematch
        echo "Checking overlay"
        case $APP_NAME in
          projecthub)
            echo "We are building an instance of $APP_NAME"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            cp ../../base/overlays/projecthub/* ../../base/
            |
            cat <<EOF >> ../../base/kustomization.yaml
              - service-backend.yaml
              - deployment-backend-talk2me.yaml
              - persistentvolumeclaim-backend.yaml
            EOF
            ;;
          *)
            echo "We are building a basic web application instance"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            ;;
        esac
........
```

or this one

```
build-yaml-manifest:
........
........

  script:
     - |
        shopt -s nocasematch
        echo "Checking overlay"
        case $APP_NAME in
          projecthub)
            echo "We are building an instance of $APP_NAME"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            cp ../../base/overlays/projecthub/* ../../base/
            |-
            cat <<EOF >> ../../base/kustomization.yaml
              - service-backend.yaml
              - deployment-backend-talk2me.yaml
              - persistentvolumeclaim-backend.yaml
            EOF
            ;;
          *)
            echo "We are building a basic web application instance"
            cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
            cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
            ;;
        esac
........
```

it will say `syntax error near unexpected token '|'` error message.

What's the good syntax for achieving what I am trying to do there?

Comment: If you indent the `EOF` token of a here-doc, you have to use `<<-EOF`, and the indentation must be TAB characters, not spaces. Otherwise, the token must be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Barmar Trying this also fails :
```       - |
            cat <<-EOF >> ../../base/kustomization.yaml
              - service-backend.yaml
              - deployment-backend-talk2me.yaml
              - persistentvolumeclaim-backend.yaml
            EOF
```

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, so that's not useful.

Comment: You're right, it's just to let you see. But what you suggest is not working for me. Did  you try on  your end?

Comment: I don't use Gitlab-CI, so I haven't tried it. It was just one of the common problems people have with heredocs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I shoudn't put my cat statement in multiline as I was already in a multiline string from the beginning of the block. I also removed indentation. So this works.

```
build-yaml-manifest:
........
........

  script:
    - |
      shopt -s nocasematch
      echo "Checking overlay"
      case $APP_NAME in
        projecthub)
          echo "We are building an instance of $APP_NAME"
          cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
          cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
          cp ../../base/overlays/projecthub/* ../../base/
          cat <<EOF >> ../../base/kustomization.yaml
       - service-backend.yaml
       - deployment-backend-talk2me.yaml
       - persistentvolumeclaim-backend.yaml
       EOF
          ;;
        *)
          echo "We are building a basic web application instance"
          cp ../../base/overlays/kustomization.yaml .
          cp ../../base/overlays/template-realm.json .
          ;;
      esac
........
```